# Load LoginViewController before SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm trying to create a view which have a side-window menu using SWRevealViewController. In the menu, I need to load UserID from LoginViewController and load the user name and photo in it. I used NSUserDefault for this. The problem is, whenever I logged out and login back using different account, the new account name and photo will stack up with the previous instead of rewrite it.

After looking here and there, I found that the problem may because the loginviewcontroller loaded after navigationcontroller and the navigationcontroller loaded after swrevealviewcontroller. I tried to move the rootview to uiloinviewcontroller but it's not working because of the navigationcontroller.

I also tried to clear the NSUserDefault when I hit logout button but nothing seems working.

Can you please help me, how I can fixed this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to clear LoginViewController's content when logout?

Comment: Do you mean clear the NSUserDefault in LoginViewController? When I hit logout button, all NSUserDefault should be reset to null

Comment: No, I mean clear the UILabel of user name and UIImage of photo of LoginViewController and reload it after user login.

Comment: r u using storyboard if yes show the screen shot of your storyboard